# In Pepper, How to take a backup and Erase the existing packages?

Tags: robotics, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I am fairly new to the robotics development track and I am working on softbank's robot Pepper. When our team received this robot, which was already utilized for some initial launching event in our company, the robot has some existing code related to that event. How and where do I access such code in the robot? If I want to change/ remove this code, how do I take the backup of that code, remove it and restart the robot? When I hit the ip address of the robot in a browser, I do see the installed applications but it does not have anything that seems relevant to that event. Using Choregraphe, I tried to see the application xar files and code, but I can only see that there is a xar file, but cannot access the behavior structure/flow or the code related to it on double clicking the xar file. Can someone help me with this?

Pepper Naoqi/ Choregraphe version used: 2.5.5

Answer (score 1):

All applications installed on Pepper are in `/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/`; you can ssh onto the robot and look at them, copy them, etc. - but you should never manually put files in there yourself; that should only be done by Choregraphe or by the cloud package update system. You also shouldn't delete the applications there; delete them through Choregraphe or (probably the best for your case once you did your backups), do a [factory reset](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/family/pepper_user_guide/setting_menu_advanced_pep.html).